# Custom local host ip too slow

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp, localhost

I'm using **Xammp (version 7.1.9-0)** in **64bit windows 10 pro** computer. 
My **default local host load much faster**.

---

But **if i change it for some custom ip address `127.0.0.3`something like that my page refresh time is too long**.

---

it **take more that 30 seconds to load a page**. This is really bother to me my project. I have read other post how to fast local host, i did some of them. seems worked for default `http://localhost` But i need that fast in any custom ip address too.

Comment: no one know? :(